# Conditional expectation of a random walk given that it is positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, random-walk

Let $\{\xi_k\}$ is a sequence of iid random variables with $E(\xi_1)=0$ and $E(\xi_1)^2=\sigma^2<\infty$. Define the random walk $Y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k$. Is it necessarily true that the conditional expectation $E(Y_n|Y_n>0)=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

From the classical CLT, we know that $\frac{Y_n}{\sqrt{n}}\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$, in which the arrow denotes weak convergence as $n\rightarrow\infty$. This seems to heavily support the suggested limiting behavior, as do the results of some computations I've done with specific choices for $\{\xi_k\}$. However, I'm stuck on how to prove the bound concretely. Is there some twist on CLT that I'm just not seeing, or is there more to the picture? Maybe I need to assume more on the random walk in question.

Any assistance provided will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that this is the answer you are looking for. But Try proving that $(Y_n)^2-n \sigma^2$ is a Martingale. This gives you that the mean of $(Y_n)^2$ is $n \sigma^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W_n=n^{-1/2}Y_n$. Then

$$
n^{-1/2}\mathsf{E}[Y_n\mid Y_n>0]=\mathsf{E}[W_n\mid W_n>0]\le \frac{\sqrt{\mathsf{E}|W_n|^2}}{\mathsf{P}(W_n>0)}=\frac{\sigma}{\mathsf{P}(W_n>0)},
$$

and $\mathsf{P}(W_n>0)\to 1/2$ (by the CLT), i.e., for any $\epsilon>0$, $\mathsf{P}(W_n>0)\ge \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Ah, I was so close! I tried going down this route, but I didn't see the Jensen's Inequality. Thank you!